# Char array basics in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
char p[3][6]={{'a','b','c','\0'},{'d','e','f','\0'},{'g','h','i','\0'}};
char s[3][6]={"abc","def","ghi"};
```

Are they both same? If different please explain what way and how it is stored in memory?

Comment: The difference is the first one doesn't compile: http://ideone.com/QrxZff.

Comment: he meant `char p[3][6]={{'a','b','c','\0'},{'d','e','f','\0'},{'g','h','i','\0' }};` I think.

Comment: Yes Elazar.. It compiled in gcc

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's because you're too strict: C89 compiles it just fine, but it [produces garbage output](http://ideone.com/SGLXMW).

Comment: sorry. Now i edited it

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That's not C89, that's just lack of `-Wall`...

Comment: [They are different](http://ideone.com/YTjv7a).

Comment: Now the question has been edited, the answer is: they are the same.

Comment: talking about ideone - here is its [yes](http://ideone.com/KCDeCa)

Comment: No difference.In char s[0]="abc\0"; null is implicitly added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no difference** in any of two methods, Try the following code and see the result 
Result for both variables p and s are same.

- In first definition you've provided string in the form of array of characters by using Single Quotes.
- Whereas in Second definition you've provided direct string by Double quotes - **Both are same**

---

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int i,j=0;
        char p[3][6]={{'a','b','c','\0'},{'d','e','f','\0'},{'g','h','i','\0'}};
        char s[3][6]={"abc","def","ghi"};
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            printf("%s",p[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            printf("%s",s[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Here is the result:

```
First 2-d string is : abc        def     ghi
Second 2-d string is :abc        def     ghi
```

Comment: but, `char *c[3] = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };` *is* different. Worth noting.

Comment: Yes, If you are talking about this pointer array to character, then you are  right.

Comment: ya understood. thanks. what will happen if i dont give'\0' in the first statement

Answer (score 3):

They're the same in memory. Here in the VS 2010 debugger, I cast to char* so I can inspect the first 18 raw bytes of p and s:
[image: screenshot of program in Visual Studio]